# Tracking calls to java servlet

Tags: java, api, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

Im running a little web api and want to include some logging methods for debugging purposes. Therfor, i want to include http calls returning information like "api calls per hour", "successfull calls vs unseccessfull calls" and so on.

I searched the internet but didnt found lots of information about that topic. Can anyone provide me with a good source or strategie for doing that?

Comment: You can implement this with `Filter` and custom counters/monitors.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I won't go easy on this. While the `Filter` will get before the servlet in the process chain, the counters won't be easy to maintain, remember that both filters and servlets are used in a multi thread environment. More info: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah. In no way is this easy. For OP, this type of data is useful in [OAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations,_administration_and_management). You can either maintain (with all the problems of synchronizing) the counters in memory (bad) or do it in database and let it handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a servlet filter to log statistics. [Here's an example](http://blog.actuanceconsulting.com/servlet-filter-java-performance-logging/).

Comment: There are two problems with the provided link: 1) It doesn't provide a counter per servlet instance (or URL) that supports multi thread. 2) To measure real time performance you must use `System.nanoTime` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis` since the former is more accurate.

Comment: Thank you. This link seems to be really helpful as a scaffold to work on.